# React Admin: Seperate exported list entries by column

Tags: typescript, export, react-admin

I am working with a React Admin TS list. I need to implement the option to export this list as a csv file. For now, I managed to make use of the React Admin "exporter" prop to add the export button which in fact exports the list as a csv file. However, the list is not formated properly. The individual entries are seperated properly per line but are all stored in the same column. Ideally, each header would be stored in a seperate column.

This is what an entry of the list looks like in the Database:

```
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "656dea9cd2af7d0329f416df"
  },
  "date": "2023-12-04T15:05:00.724Z",
  "author": {
    "id": 1234,
    "fullName": "Test User"
  },
  "resource": "tasks",
  "action": "changedCurrentStage",
  "payload": "Some example Text like Hello World",
  "__v": 0
}
```

And here is the frontend part of the code for the list view itself:

```
import { ListItemAvatar, Card, CardContent } from '@mui/material';
import { EventAvatar } from '@react-admin/ra-audit-log';
import {
  Datagrid,
  DateField,
  List,
  Pagination,
  TextField,
  SavedQueriesList,
  FilterList,
  FilterListItem,
  FilterLiveSearch,
  downloadCSV,
} from 'react-admin';
import React from 'react';
import FilterIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Filter';

interface AuditLogRecord {
  id: number;
  author: {
    fullName: string;
  };
  action: string;
  resource: string;
  payload: string;
  date: string;
}

const exporter = (records: AuditLogRecord[] | undefined) => {
  if (!records) {
    return;
  }

  const csvHeaders = ['ID', 'Author', 'Aktion', 'resource', 'Payload', 'Zeitpunkt'];

  // Format the CSV header
  const csvHeader = csvHeaders.join('\t');

  // Format the CSV data with tabs
  const csvData = records
    .map((record) =>
      [
        record.id,
        `"${record.author.fullName}"`,
        `"${record.action}"`,
        `"${record.resource}"`,
        `"${record.payload}"`,
        `"${record.date}"`,
      ].join('\t'),
    )
    .join('\n');

  const csvContent = `${csvHeader}\n${csvData}`;

  downloadCSV(csvContent, 'auditLog'); // download as 'auditLog.csv`
};

export const SciAuditLogList = () => {
  return (
    <List
      title='auditLog'
      pagination={<Pagination rowsPerPageOptions={[10, 25, 50, 100]} />}
      exporter={exporter}>
      <Datagrid
        bulkActionButtons={false}
        sx={{ '& .RaDatagrid-headerRow span': { fontSize: 'medium' }, maxWidth: '100%' }}
        rowClick='show'>
        <ListItemAvatar>
          <EventAvatar
            alt={'author.fullName'}
            src={'author.avatar'}
            fullName={'author.fullName'}
            role='presentation'
          />
        </ListItemAvatar>

        <TextField source='author.fullName' label='Author' color={'red'} />
        <TextField source='action' label='Action' />
        <TextField source='resource' label='Resource' />
        <TextField source='payload' label='Payload' />
        {/* <JsonFormatter source='payload' label='Payload'/> */}
        <DateField source='date' label='Zeitpunkt' showTime />
      </Datagrid>
    </List>
  );
};
```

My idea is that somehow the data for the entry is not formated properly. As in, Excel needs the data to be arranged in a certain way to seperate the entry headers by column meaning a simple comma is not enough. I however failed to determine this proper formating. Any ideas?

I have tried seperating the headers and contents both by comma and tab, neither of which helped. My next idea would be to change the formating of the data itself, but I am unsure as to how I would have to do that.

Comment: Can you share an example of a CSV file you have so far? Also, if my recollection is correct, Excel uses a default separator that is **region dependant** (idk why...). You may want to set-up your Excel to use a different separator by default ([this link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/office/import-or-export-text-txt-or-csv-files-5250ac4c-663c-47ce-937b-339e391393ba) might help). Alternatively, you can try using your own [exporter](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/List.html#exporter) to change the separator character.